# Android: How to set permissions for integrated Twitter Account to only tweet/post to timeline?

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth

I just integrated Twitter with OAuth into my Android application, and now I wanted to change the rigths of my application. Instead of all the listed rights in my screenshot, **I just want my app to publish tweets at the timeline**. (don't want to scare people of, because I don't want to have access to their profile...)
[image]

But I'm a bit lost with the twitter-API and the only thing I found so far, is in the Application settings to change the `Application Type` to 'Read',`Read & Write` or `Read & Write and Access direct messages`.

So question is: **How can I limit the permissions of my application?**

```
//f.e. Integration Facebook SDK: here you can set different types,like
// "only allow application to post something in your name"...
.setPublishPermissions(Arrays.asList("publish_stream"))
```

Comment: Hey did you ever find an answer for this? - I'm stuck on it too.

Comment: nope, there s nothing hidden in their api, so i guess it s not possible...

Comment: Right, all I managed to do was change my apps permissions from the highest to Read and Write (which is only a bit better)

Comment: I am also facing same issue, even I just want to use it for login in only. Don't need any other information or private information from logged in user. Still it asks for all these permissions that are useless.