# How can I change the application's access permission of twitter in android?

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I have integrated twitter in my application using twitter 4j library for login purpose only.
In my twitter login page it is showing

This application will be able to

- Read tweets from your timeline
- See who you follow and follow new people
- Update your profile
- Post tweets for you

I want to remove some permissions, I already seen [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088175/android-how-to-set-permissions-for-integrated-twitter-account-to-only-tweet-pos) and didn't get any idea. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to  https://apps.twitter.com/app/...>> click on the app you created for using >> click on permissions tab..you can modify permissions there

Comment: There are only 3 option. 1. Read only 2. Read and Write 3. Read, Write and Access direct messages. Even you select Read only, it asks for read tweets, get followers etc permissions. Any idea ?

Comment: I can't even seem to find any of those permissions. my app settings doesn't have permissions

Comment: Same thing here. I have no permissions for my app.

Comment: Just go to User authentication settings and enable oauth 1.0a and 2.0

Answer (score 5):

1. First open the setting for the app whose permission you want to change.
2. Click on this option
   [image]
3. click on edit
4. Switch to 1.0 and enter your website details
   [image]
5. Click save
6. Now go to keys section and re-generate the Access keys